# Rails: Using form (collection select) to call show-action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

A model named 'book' with attributes 'name' and 'id' is given. How can i use this collection select to call the show-action of a certain book? The one code mentioned below returns the following error message:

**Couldn't find Book with ID=book_id**

```
<% form_tag(book_path(:book_id)), :method => :get  do %>
  <p>
  <%= label(:book, :id, 'Show Book:') %>
    <%= @books = Books.find(:all, :order => :name)
      collection_select(:book, :id, @books, :id, :name) 
  %> 
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`book_path` is generated once only, for the form tag itself. It won't be updated whenever your selection changes.

When you submit that form, it's going to request the following URL:

```
/books/book_id?book[id]=5
```

Since your `book_path` thinks book_id is the ID number you wanted, it tries to look that up. You could do what you want you by changing the code in your controller from:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
```

to:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:book][:id])
```

But it kind of smells bad so be warned.

Comment: Thanks a lot Luke. Any suggestion for a non-smelly solution? I just need a drop-down menu to select a certain book to show...

Comment: Because the "smelly-solution" would break default-calls to the show action using book_path(id), wouldn't it?

Comment: You could try to select the ID from either field, like so:

@book = Book.find(params[:book].try(:[],:id) || params[:id])

That would work, but the smell still persists because you're not technically supposed to use RESTful routes like that. Balance 'getting it done' with 'following conventions'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new route that is not based on the id, like

```
get 'books/show'    # put this above your "resources :books"
```

and change your form to

```
<% form_tag books_show_path, :method => :get %>
```